# How can I update my kinematic object's rotation based on how much it has moved per frame?

Tags: unity, 2d, rotation

I'm moving a kinematic circle (and its child sprite) horizontally back and forth after a delay using `transform.Translate()`. I'm wondering how I can find a suitable rotation value for my circle based on the amount it has moved per frame, almost like what one would expect if he or she was rolling a coin across a desk.

I've tried using a pre-selected `rotationSpeed` value, but this conflicts with the variable velocity produced by using acceleration; and updating `transform.eulerAngles.z` with the current velocity causes the circle to rotate way too much every frame (multiplying the velocity by `Time.deltaTime` causes it to move far too little).

I suspect there is a mathematical way to derive what I'm looking for based on the amount moved and the size of the circle, but do not know where to begin with this.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RotatingCircle2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float moveSpeed = 9f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float acceleration = 25f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float reverseTime = 3f;

    private float velocityX = 0;
    private float directionX = 1;

    private float timer = 0;

    private void Update()
    {
        MoveAndRotate();
    }

    private void MoveAndRotate()
    {
        if (timer >= reverseTime)
        {
            directionX *= -1;
            timer = 0;
        }

        // Move
        velocityX = Mathf.MoveTowards(velocityX, moveSpeed * directionX, acceleration * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * velocityX * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

        // Rotate
        float targetRotationZ = transform.eulerAngles.z + velocityX * Time.deltaTime; // This isn't right...
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, targetRotationZ);
        transform.rotation = targetRotation;

        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR: A circle will rotate 360 degrees every time it travels a distance equal to its circumference.**

I stumbled upon the [Coin Rotation Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_rotation_paradox), which helped me to better understand this problem.

A circle with radius `r = 1` has a circumference `2 * Pi * 1 = 6.28`. Rolling this circle around another circle with radius `r = 3` and circumference `2 * Pi * 3 = 18.84` causes the circle to complete **four 360 degree rotations**, which seems counter intuitive because the circumference of the circle around which it is rotating is only three times as large. But the path of motion around the larger circle is also a circle with radius `r = 1 + 3`, the distance of both the original circles' radii added together. The initial circle will thus move a total distance of **four times its circumference**, or `2 * Pi * (3 + 1) = 25.12`. This path is shown below in blue:

[image]

This means that a circle will rotate 360 degrees every time it travels a distance equal to its circumference. Indeed, the cited Wikipedia article shows that rolling the original circle over the straight line made from the unraveled circumference of the second circle with radius `r = 3` causes that circle to only rotate three times, as the total distance traveled is just 3 times its circumference.

So, to rotate a circle as it moves around the game:

1. Find the circumference of the circle
2. Get the amount moved this frame
3. Divide this amount by the circumference to get the ratio of movement : circumference
4. Add to or subtract from the circle's z rotation this ratio multiplied by 360

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CircleCollider2D))]
public class RotatingCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float moveSpeed = 9f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float acceleration = 25f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float reverseTime = 3f;

    private CircleCollider2D circleCollider;
    private float circumference;

    private float velocityX = 0;
    private float directionX = 1;

    private float timer = 0;

    private void Awake()
    {
        circleCollider = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
        circumference = 2 * Mathf.PI * (circleCollider.radius * transform.localScale.x);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        MoveAndRotate();
    }

    private void MoveAndRotate()
    {
        if (timer >= reverseTime)
        {
            directionX *= -1;
            timer = 0;
        }

        // Move
        velocityX = Mathf.MoveTowards(velocityX, moveSpeed * directionX, acceleration * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * velocityX * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

        // Rotate
        float movementToCircumferenceRatio = Mathf.Abs(velocityX * Time.deltaTime) / circumference;
        float rotationAmount = 360 * movementToCircumferenceRatio;

        float targetRotationZ = transform.eulerAngles.z - rotationAmount * Mathf.Sign(velocityX);
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, targetRotationZ);
        transform.rotation = targetRotation;

        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```